# How can I increase my population

Tags: tropico-5

I am currently on the mission Back to the past! And have a really good economy. My only problem is, that I lag a large enough workforce.

**How can I increase the population on my island?**

Comment: I haven't played 5 but in previous versions you can control the immigration coming into your island via the immigration office and passing certain edicts, do you have access to those?

Comment: From what I understand, Tropico 5 works purely on the idea of "If you build it, they will come". If there are jobs and houses, people will be more inclined to immigrate. @z': I haven't yet played the last chapter, but this seems to be a constitutional option now, rather than a quickly adjustable settings.

Answer (score 7):

From what I can see, there are three main ways to attract Immigrants.

1. Approval Rating. I believe if your approval rating is high you attract more immigrants to Tropico. This can be annoying, as you may need to build more buildings in order to fix the apporoval, in order to attract more people to staff said buildings. You may need to shut down some industries or something to do this.
2. Constitution. You can change the immigration policy in your Constitution. The "Immigrant Nation" option will increase the number of uneducated people who show up. This cannot be changed regularly, and has a fairly long cooldown between changes.
3. Quests. A number of quests have additional people as rewards. Things like "5 more communists" or "10 educated capitalists" or something. This is far from reliable, as you can't choose what quests you are offered.

You can also increase the Birth Rate on your island. This can be done by enacting the "Contraception Ban" edict, and by upgrading clinics and hospitals with an "Obstetrics Wing".

Answer (score 1):

To increase the population of you tropico you will need to give them a reason to visit your island like luxury buildings and entertainment buildings to get more people to immagrate to your island.
If you are having bad trouble with population make sure when you write your constitution you are setting it to an immigrant nation.